# OCCI : Connecting to OracleDB using SSL wallet authentication

Tags: c++, oracle, ssl-certificate, occi, oracle-wallet

I'm fairly new to the OracleDB. I'm looking into connecting client applications to the Oracle DB on a server without providing username and password.  Is my understanding is correct that this can be achieved using the `orapki` wallet?
I'm using my laptop to test this by acting as both client and server.

I'm using`orapki` to **create wallets** for client and server side as shown below:

```
Create Server Wallet :
orapki wallet create -wallet "C:/app/wallet" -pwd Welcome1 -auto_login
orapki wallet add -wallet "C:/app/wallet" -pwd Welcome1 -dn "CN=MyHostName" -keysize 1024 -self_signed -validity 3650 -sign_alg sha256
orapki wallet export -wallet "C:/app/wallet" -pwd Welcome1 -dn "CN=MyHostName" -cert C:/app/wallet/MyHostName-certificate.crt
```

```
Create Client Wallet: [I choose CN name to match username for oracleDB login name, i.e., abcd]
orapki wallet create -wallet "C:/app/client_wallet" -pwd Welcome1 -auto_login
orapki wallet add -wallet "C:/app/client_wallet" -pwd Welcome1 -dn "CN=abcd" -keysize 1024 -self_signed -validity 3650 -sign_alg sha256
orapki wallet export -wallet "C:/app/client_wallet" -pwd Welcome1 -dn "CN=abcd" -cert C:/app/client_wallet/abcd-certificate.crt
```

**Load certificate** from one side to the wallet on the other side.

```
Load the server certificate into the client wallet.
orapki wallet add -wallet "C:/app/client_wallet" -pwd Welcome1 -trusted_cert -cert C:/app/wallet/MyHostName-certificate.crt
```

```
Load the Client certificate into the server wallet.
orapki wallet add -wallet "C:/app/wallet" -pwd Welcome1 -trusted_cert -cert C:/app/client_wallet/abcd-certificate.crt
```

**Displaying wallets** gives below results:

```
Server Wallet:
orapki wallet display -wallet "C:/app/wallet" -pwd Welcome1

Oracle PKI Tool : Version 12.1.0.2
Copyright (c) 2004, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Requested Certificates:
User Certificates:
Subject:        CN=MyHostName
Trusted Certificates:
Subject:        CN=abcd
Subject:        CN=MyHostName
```

```
Client Wallet:
orapki wallet display -wallet "C:/app/client_wallet" -pwd Welcome1

Oracle PKI Tool : Version 12.1.0.2
Copyright (c) 2004, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Requested Certificates:
User Certificates:
Subject:        CN=abcd
Trusted Certificates:
Subject:        CN=MyHostName
Subject:        CN=abcd
```

My understanding from above is that the server and client now trusted each other and hence good for establishing connections.

**Server** settings files as shown below:

**tnsnames.ora**

```
TCP_ACTIVE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MyHostName)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

TCPS_ACTIVE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = MyHostName)(PORT = 1522))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

**listener.ora**

```
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = TRUE

WALLET_LOCATION =
  (SOURCE =
    (METHOD = FILE)
    (METHOD_DATA =
      (DIRECTORY = C:\app\wallet)
    )
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\MyUser\product\12.1.0\dbhome_2)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\MyUser\product\12.1.0\dbhome_2\bin\oraclr12.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MyHostName)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = MyHostName)(PORT = 1522))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

**sqlnet.ora**

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (BEQ, TCPS, NTS)
SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE = FALSE

#SSL_VERSION = 0

TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT = SUPPORT

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = TRUE

WALLET_LOCATION =
  (SOURCE =
    (METHOD = FILE)
    (METHOD_DATA =
      (DIRECTORY = C:\app\wallet)
    )
  )

#SSL_CIPHER_SUITES= (SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA)
```

I have a simple c++ test **client** using OCCI with setting files as shown below

**tnsnames.ora**

```
TCP_ACTIVE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MyHostName)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

TCPS_ACTIVE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = MyHostName)(PORT = 1522))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

**sqlnet.ora**

```
TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT=support

WALLET_LOCATION =
  (SOURCE =
    (METHOD = FILE)
    (METHOD_DATA =
      (DIRECTORY = C:\app\client_wallet)
    )
  )



SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION =TRUE
SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH=OFF
TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT = 16
TRACE_FILE_CLIENT = client_trace
TRACE_TIMESTAMP_CLIENT = ON 
TRACE_DIRECTORY_CLIENT = C:\Client 
DIAG_ADR_ENABLED=ON
```

My server **Listener Service status** is as shown below:

```
LSNRCTL> status
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHostName)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                24-OCT-2019 19:46:17
Uptime                    0 days 21 hr. 31 min. 25 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   C:\app\MyUser\product\12.1.0\dbhome_2\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\app\MyUser\diag\tnslsnr\MyHostName\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=MyHostName)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=MyHostName)(PORT=1522)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=MyHostName)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=C:\app\wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orcl" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orclXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

When I try to connect to the server using connection string "**TCP_ACTIVE**" and supply username and password, I'm **able to connect normally**

```
Environment *env = Environment::createEnvironment();                        
Connection *conn = env->createConnection(m_username.c_str(), m_password.c_str(), m_dbConnectionString.c_str());
```

The connection in "conn" seems to form and able to use it to run simple query successfully.

But when I'm trying to connect to the server using **TCPS_ACTIVE** connection string, I'm able to connect only when I supply the username and the password. Below is the error message I got when I don't supply the user name and password:

```
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

I am curious if it is possible to connect to the server using the wallet and without using a username and password? If so, how should I set it up for test?

Thank you

P.S. : I've look into [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762885/using-oracle-wallet-authentication-from-oci) but I can't understand how the setting was done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my user needs to be identified externally as "CN=abcd" for it to work.
Go to SQL Developer with admin login and run :

```
alter user abcd identified externally as 'CN=abcd';
```

Above code able to connect without using the password.